# Is it possible to "forward" a video feed from a monitor to a tv over hdmi?

Tags: video, display, hdmi

I have a monitor that has both a vga and hdmi input.  I am wondering if I can use the HDMI to mirror the input from the VGA to a secondary tv.  Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Short answer is 'No'. Monitor's and TV's are both peripheral outputs, thus they both accept inputs. I said all that to say: the easiest way would be to 'split' the video going into the monitor with either a VGA splitter or HDMI splitter, should you decide on hi def :-)  Those hardware devices are googlable.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because the monitor has only inputs. But you could buy a vga/hdmi splitter, or check if your computer graphics card has an HDMI or DVI output besides the VGA.

Answer (score 0):

No. But I'm sure that your PC has two video outputs: VGA and DVI or HDMI. DVI is actually HDMI-compatible and you can buy very cheap adapters. Just connect your TV via HDMI and set up PC to mirror image.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options..

If the source is a computer and it does has a modern VGA Card, with HDMI and DVI outputs, you can connect the monitor on the DVI and the HDMI output will be avaible.. Or use a DVI-to-HDMI adapter.

You can aswell look for an HDMI Signal Multiplier, like the one about, which is only $49.99

[http://www.amazon.com/J-Tech-Digital-Splitter-Certified-Bandwidth/dp/B002WPAU38](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WPAU38)

Good luck